# all the checkboxes are uncheked while unchecking single checkbox - react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

There is a list. With every item is having a checkbox. If user clicks 'select all' then all the checkboxes will be checked. Now problem is if user uncheck one checkbox then all the checkboxes are unchecked. How to resist that? One more problem is how to add checked items(not unchecked ones) to other list.

here i have done so far:

**action code**

```
//select all checkboxes
export const selectAllBoxes = () =>({
   type : SELECT_ALL_CHECKBOX
});

//selected checkbox remove unchecked one
export const checkboxState = mruCode =>({
  type: GET_CHECKBOX,
  payload : mruCode
});

//add selected ones
export const checkedLocation = () =>({
  type: GET_CHECKED_LOCATION
});
```

**reducer code**

```
case 'SELECT_ALL_CHECKBOX':
         return {
             ...state,
             isChecked: state.location
         }

        case 'GET_CHECKBOX':
        let newList = state.isChecked.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode ===action.payload)
        return{
             ...state,
             isChecked: newList
        }
        case 'GET_CHECKED_LOCATION':
          return{
              ...state,
              conLocations:[...state.isChecked]
          }
```

**component code snippet**(select all and checkbox view snippet)

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            chkitems: []
        };
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleChecklocation = this.handleChecklocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedAdded = this.handleCheckedAdded.bind(this);
        this.checkedAllLocation = this.checkedAllLocation.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null){
            this.props.initLocationData(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }
    /**componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(nextProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData))) {
            console.log(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
            this.props.initLocationData(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }*/

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(prevProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData)))) {
            this.props.initLocationData(this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }


    togglePanel(e) {
        this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    }
    handleRemove(mruCode) {
        this.props.removeLocation(mruCode)
    }
    handleClick(mruCode) {
        this.props.addLocation(mruCode)
    }
    allLocations() {
        this.props.addAllLocation()
    }
    clearall() {
        this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }

    handleChecklocation(mruCode) {
        this.props.checkboxState(mruCode);
    }

    handleCheckedAdded() {
        this.props.checkedLocation()
    }

    checkedAllLocation(){
        this.props.selectAllBoxes()
    }

    /** updating locationData by saving changes - calling this function into jobsPanel */
    getLocationData() {
        let saveableLocationlist = [];
        if (this.props.conLocations != null) {
            const { conLocations } = this.props;
            saveableLocationlist = conLocations;
        }
        const locationData = {
            locationDetails: saveableLocationlist
        }
        return locationData;
    }

    render() {
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e) => this.togglePanel(e)}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                            <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                            <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.props.conLocations.map((loc, index) => <span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}{index < this.props.conLocations.length - 1 ? ',\u00A0' : ''}</span>)}
                                <span onClick={(e) => this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {this.state.open ? (
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <div className="row grid-divider">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <div className="col-padding"><div className="pos-div"><h4>Locations List</h4><a data-target="toggle" data-target="#myCheckbox" className="jdClickable1" onClick={()=>this.checkedAllLocation()}>Select all</a><button style={{ display: this.props.location.length === this.props.conLocations.length ? "none" : "block" }} className="allLargeBtn" onClick={() => this.handleCheckedAdded()}>Add Checked Locations</button></div><hr />
                                    {this.props.location.map((item, index) => (
                                        <div key={index}><div><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => this.handleChecklocation(item.mruCode)} checked={this.props.isChecked.length===this.props.location.length ? true:false} /><label></label><span className="locationNameSpan">{item.mruCode} - {_labels[item.division]} - {item.country}</span>{!this.props.conLocations.find(item2 => item.mruCode === item2.mruCode) && (<div className="pull-right jd"><button className="call-to-action" onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.mruCode)}>Add Location</button></div>)}<hr /></div></div>))}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>) : null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        location: state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations,
        isChecked: state.locationRed.isChecked
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return  bindActionCreators({
        loadData,
        addLocation,
        addAllLocation,
        removeLocation,
        removeAllLocation,
        checkboxState,
        checkedLocation,
        initLocationData,
        selectAllBoxes
    },  dispatch);
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(NewLocationPanel);
```

What will be the correct way to uncheck/check and add selected items. Flow will be like - **select all(click) -> checked all checkboxes -> user input(deselect optional) -> remaining Checked boxes(if deselect) -> addtolist(button onClick)**

Comment: Please write the functions outside the HTML of your elements, so the code is readable

Comment: @GalAbra It is common pattern for `React`, it is called `jsx`.

Comment: @Klimenkomud I'm well familiar with `jsx`. However this is a very bad practice to write such long one-line functions. It's especially unpreferable when it's a part of a question that should be well explained.

Comment: Please, put to your question code of whole component, without some methods it is hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: i have added whole component

Answer (score 0):

**Actions code:**

```js
//select and unselect all checkboxes
export const toggleAllBoxes = () =>({
   type : "TOGGLE_ALL_CHECKBOXES"
});

//Toggle a checkbox
export const toggleCheckbox = mruCode =>({
  type: "TOGGLE_CHECKBOX",
  payload : mruCode
});
```

**Reducer code**

```js
case 'TOGGLE_ALL_CHECKBOXES':
  let checkedBoxes = state.checkedBoxes && state.checkedBoxes.length > 0 ? []: [...state.location]
   return {
       ...state,
       checkedBoxes: checkedBoxes
   }

case 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX': {
  let id = action.payload
  let exists = false;
  let newList = []
  state.checkedBoxes.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.mruCode === id) {
          exists = true;
      }
  });
  if(exists)
    newList = state.checkedBoxes.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode !=id)
    else {
      let newItem = state.location.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode === id);
      newList = [...state.checkedBoxes, ...newItem]
    }

  return{
       ...state,
       checkedBoxes: newList
  }
}
```

You can do all your operations with these two actions.

To show checked items, you can re-use the checkedBoxes array in the state.

Comment: If you elaborate your reducer code then it will be helpful for me. Because three operation is needed  1. select all 2. user can deselect some checkboxes 3. after 2nd operation user can add those checked to other list

Answer (score 0):

Requirement and the logic are not matching for the checkbox. I meant below code.

```
case 'GET_CHECKBOX':
    let newList = state.isChecked.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode ===action.payload)
    return{
         ...state,
         isChecked: newList
}
```

You are passing an item `mruCode` to the dispatcher function.
In the redux state, it would be better if you maintain an array of checked items. Basically an array of mruCode's. In that case this.props.isChecked will be an array. For checkbox you have to check that array for checked attribute.

```
checked={ this.props.isChecked.includes(item.mruCode) }
```

UPDATE: Reducer Code

```
 case 'GET_CHECKBOX':
    let newList = state.isChecked.includes(mruCode) ?
       state.isChecked.filter( mruCode => mruCode !== action.payload) :
       state.isChecked.concat(action.payload)
    return{
         ...state,
         isChecked: newList
}
```

Above code removes mruCode if already it's checked, otherwise, it will get appended.

For checking all checkboxes

```
case 'TOGGLE_ALL_CHECKBOXES':
  let checkedBoxes = state.location.map( item => item.mruCode )
  return {
    ...state,
    isChecked: checkedBoxes
  }
```

Comment: Yes i am trying to do that only. Will you please explain what is the problem on that code? Because i am taking all those checked items not the unchecked ones and adding to other list via onClick button function. Hope you understand what i am trying to do

Comment: Am i doing right in Ui component , calling select all event and checkbox checked part? Because  now if i deselect any checkbox then all the checkbox are deselected

Comment: You have to replace the checked attribute of checkbox to `checked={ this.props.isChecked.includes(item.mruCode) }`

Comment: in your updated reducer code 'GET_CHECKBOX' . mruCode params in includes is not defined. Yes checked attribute and select all is working fine.

Comment: Have you initialised state.isChecked ??

Comment: const initialState={
      location:[],
      conLocations:[],
      currList: [],
      isChecked : []
};   did you mean to this? initialState

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196895/discussion-between-ajay-varghese-and-user7411584).